# JOSM plugin not working

Tags: openstreetmap, plugins, josm

I have been trying to use a PicLayer plugin in the JOSM editor, however after installing the plugin it would never appear in the top menu next to Windows, Audio, Help dropdowns (at least that's where I think it should be). I must say I am totally new to JOSM, and I do have no idea on how to even uninstall that plugin, so I could give it another try installing it back (so it hopefully shows now).

Answer (score 3):

The PicLayer plugin adds new items to the `Imagery/More…` menu item. There you will find the following new items:

- New picture Layer from file
- New picture Layer from clipboard